Query to get the IDs where all the records in parent child relationship meet a criteria of date being less than 1/1/2024
my data set is as follows:



ID
EndDate




1
12/31/2023


1
12/30/2023


1
12/29/2023


2
12/29/2023


2
12/29/2023


2
NULL



From this data set, I only want to get the record with ID 1 since all the records have ENDDATE not null and is less than 01.01.2024. I will not want ID 2 in my results since one of the records with ID 2 has ENDDATE = null

Please add the expected result: Do you want all rows of id 1 or one only, do you want both columns or one only? And show what you have tried and explain why it doesn't produce the expected result. Also tag the RDBMS you use.

One option is to use Count() Over() analytic function with Case expression to number rows with ENDDATE < 01.01.2024 and another that counts rows per ID. Select those where the counts are the same (all rows per ID have adequate ENDDATE):
WITH    S a m p l e    D a t a : 
    tbl (ID, ENDDATE) AS
        ( Select 1, DATE '2023-12-31' From Dual Union All 
          Select 1, DATE '2023-12-30' From Dual Union All 
          Select 1, DATE '2023-12-29' From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, DATE '2023-12-29' From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, DATE '2023-12-29' From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, NULL From Dual
        )

--    S Q L : 
SELECT  ID
FROM    ( Select  ID, ENDDATE,
                  Count(Case When ENDDATE < To_Date('01.01.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy') Then 1 End) 
                      Over(Partition By ID Order By ENDDATE 
                            Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row)  
 as COUNT_ID_ENDDATE,
                  Count(ID) Over(Partition By ID)  as COUNT_ID
          From  tbl
        )
WHERE   COUNT_ID_ENDDATE = COUNT_ID

/*  R e s u l t :
ID
--
 1    */


SELECT distinct ID FROM YourTable
WHERE ID  NOt in
(
    SELECT ID FROM YourTable 
    WHERE EndDate is null or EndDate>'2024-01-01'
)

